# Relationship between parametrization variables of hollow cylinder/rolling disk system.

Tags: geometry, physics, parametric

**Provided info**:

> A hollow cylinder (mass $m1$, radius $R$, $\delta$ << $R$) is pivoted on two mass-less bearings. In the hollow cylinder a plate (mass $m2$, radius $r$) rolls without sliding.
>
> - The moments of inertia are denoted by $I_i$.
> - The movement happens in a 2D plane (Fig. 2).

The task at hand is to "Find a connection between $\dot{\theta}$, $\dot{\psi}$ and $\dot{\phi}$."

[image: Image of system]

The provided solution states that:

> $(R-r)\dot{\theta} = R\dot{\psi} - r\dot{\phi}$, meaning that $\delta$ can be disregarded.

My own approach was to say that the distance $r\dot{\phi}$ covered by the rotation $\dot{\phi}$ of the plate would equal the distance $-R\dot{\theta}$ when the cylinder is standing still. Adding the potential shift in the surface caused by the rolling of the cylinder leads me to believe that the relationship should be:

$$r\dot{\phi} = R(\dot{\psi} - \dot{\theta})$$

Would appreciate any input on the error in my solution.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, Monkey. I will keep your improvements in mind if i pose any more questions on this site.

Answer (score 0):

There is one tiny aspect that you did not use **"rolls without sliding"**. When the surface of the cylinder rotates, this will cause an additional rotation for the $m_2$ object. So while you consider the motion of the center of mass, you need to account for the fact that the instantaneous velocities of $m_2$ and $m_1$ at the point of contact are the same.

For a circular object of radius $r$, rolling on a straight surface with angular velocity $\dot{\phi}$, the velocity at the point of contact is $0$, but the center of object (at height $r$) moves with a velocity $r \dot{\phi}$. In this case, we need to add the velocity of the surface. Accounting for the directions of increasing $\dot{\phi}$ and $\dot{\psi}$, you get the velocity of the center of $m_2$ is $R\dot{\psi}-r\dot{\phi}$. Now if you write the same velocity in terms of $\dot{\theta}$ you get $(R-r)\dot{\theta}$. By equating the two, the answer is then
$$(R-r)\dot{\theta}=R\dot{\psi}-r\dot{\phi}$$

Comment: Thanks for your input. I have one question however. You say the the velocity of the center of mass of $m_2$ is $r\dot{\phi}$. But is this not the velocity at which the point of contact moves along the cyllinder? Shouldn't the velocity at the center of mass be slightly lower by a factor of $\frac{R-r}{R}$ due to curvature? And will not the velocity influence of the surface on $m_2$, $R\dot{\psi}$ need to be multiplied by the same factor? Either that or set it equal to the velocity at radius $R$ instead of $R-r$ and keep the right side of the expression as is. Thoughts?

Comment: No. Remember that the point on the contact surface is fixed, so the curvature of the surface does not matter